# Date format in CalDav Propfind response - How to change it?

Tags: xml, date, format, icloud, caldav

I am trying to set up a CalDav Client vor iCloud. I am using the following PROPFIND http curl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">

  <d:prop>
    <d:displayname/>
    <cs:getctag/>
    <d:resource-class/>
    <d:getlastmodified/>
  </d:prop>

</d:propfind>
```

The response is something like this:

```
    <getlastmodified>Mon, 22 Jan 2018 20:03:49 GMT</getlastmodified>
    <creationdate>2013-04-02T20:12:23Z</creationdate>
    <auto-provisioned xmlns="urn:mobileme:server-to-server"/>
```

I know want to know if I can get the format of the  tag in a different format? Best would be something like 2013-04-02T20:12:23Z.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If your shell is bash you could get it like: date -d 'Mon, 22 Jan 2018 20:03:49 GMT' --iso-8601=seconds

Comment: Thanks! But I have to use curl. Do you know if there is an xml option for that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "tag" you mean the `getlastmodified` property, which returns this
date:

```
Mon, 22 Jan 2018 20:03:49 GMT
```

and you are asking whether you can make the server return that date in a
different format.
No you can't, the format of the `getlastmodified`
WebDAV property is standardized to be a
[rfc1123-date](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1)
in the
[WebDAV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-15.7) (4918).

IMPORTANT: `getlastmodified` is not a tag! If you need a tag to do
synchronization, use the
[ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3).
The [Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)
document explains this well.

What you can do is parse and reformat your `curl` output in the shell.
You could use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net)
or another tool to do this:

```
lastmod=$(curl ... | xmlstarlet sel -N x="DAV:" -t -v "//x:getlastmodified")
date -jf \
  "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" \
  +"%Y-%M-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" \
  "${lastmod}"
```

... adjust to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the information I needed.